# How to translate "to keep someone updated"?

Tags: переклад, from-english

For example, "He kept me updated on this matter". There is "Тримати в курсі" but it sounds more like a calque from Russian "держать в курсе".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe *бути в курсі*, *вводити в курс*, *тримати в курсі* and similar expressions really appeared as calques, but they were adopted more than a hundred years ago and now are perceived as “almost native”:

- *Ще не раз до того часу напишу до Вас, тож будете все **в курсі** справ* (a letter of Mykhailo Kotsiubynsky, 1911).
- *Хто хоче **стояти в курсі** справ, що дотикають українського культурного житя, той повинен передплачувати “Літературно-Науковий Вістник“* (the “Літературно-Науковий Вістник” journal, 1913).
- *— Ви не **в курсі** наших справ? <…> Це дуже зле й дуже добре, що ви не **в курсі*** (the “Божки” novel of Volodymyr Vynnychenko, 1914).
- *Щоб бути завжди **в курсі** національного життя і національних відносин, Секретарство закладає інформаційний відділ, що рівночасно подаватиме найширші відомості про національне життя на Україні* (the 2-nd Declaration of General Secretariat of Ukraine, 1917).

(From [General Regionally Annotated Corpus of Ukrainian (GRAC)](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/sortx?q=aword%2C"%D0%B2"+"%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%96"&corpname=grac3&viewmode=sen&attrs=word%2Ctag&ctxattrs=word&structs=doc&refs=%3Ddoc.author%2C%3Ddoc.title%2C%3Ddoc.date%2C%3Ddoc.genre%2C%3Ddoc.region%2C%3Ddoc.translator&pagesize=100&sattr=doc.date&skey=rc&spos=3).)

Also you may just express that directly like “he informed me”:

- *він вістував мені*
- *він давав мені знати*
- *він ділився зі мною інформацією/новинами*
- *він доводив мені інформацію/новини*
- *він доповідав мені* (“he reported me”, about making official reports to boss)
- *він інформував мене*
- *він передавав мені інформацію/новини*
- *він повідомляв мені*
- *він рапортував мені* (“he reported me”, about making official reports to boss)
- *він сповіщав мене*

(From list of semi-synonyms for *інформувати* in [Dictionaries of Ukraine on-line](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/).)